# Why SO, SU and SF allow to style the tags?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, design

Maybe it is a bug, but on SO, SF, SU and their metas is it possible to style the tags:

```
#[meta-tag:featured]
#*[meta-tag:featured]*
##[meta-tag:featured]
###[meta-tag:featured]
[meta-tag:featured]

**[meta-tag:featured]**
```

The above on MSO looks like

[image]

If it is not a bug,  why other sites of SE network don't allow to do it? For example, on MSE it doesn't change tag size

## [sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag)

### [sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag)

#### [sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag)

Of all styling I can only apply emphasis (italic): *[sometag](/questions/tagged/sometag)*.

So why tag styling is supported on SO, SU and SF? Tag styling should be completely turned off or be enabled on all sites.

Comment: The real question is why on earth do SO, SU, and SF allow to style the tags?

Comment: @mhlester I am rephrasing my question a little. ))

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: It's just the way the styling worked out. On MSO, used in your example, the font-size for tags is a percentage. Here on MSE, the font-size is an explicit pixel size - so the sizing effects of header elements around it won't do anything. Different sites, different themes, different results.

Comment: Laura, why? It was such a beautiful tag :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, we only go out of our way to block obnoxious abuse of markup when someone goes out of their way to abuse it obnoxiously.

So... y'know...

Comment: Are you seriously challenging nicael to abuse something obnoxiously? :)